# Android Studio Gradle error “Multiple dex files define…”

Tags: android, gradle, android-volley, dex, android-multidex

My Project was working fine, until I added the volley library. Then, it started giving me an error like this:

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.> java.util.zip.ZipException:
>   duplicate entry: com/android/volley/AuthFailureError.class

What should I do to fix this error?

My App gradle is below

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.snsepro.mym"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
}
ext {
    supportLibVersion = '23.1.1'  // variable that can be referenced to keep support libs consistent
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://zendesk.artifactoryonline.com/zendesk/repo' }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('libs/gcm.jar')
    compile files('libs/gcm-src.jar')
    compile files('libs/picasso-2.5.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/jsoup-1.7.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/gson-2.2.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/volley.jar')
    compile files('libs/cometchat-sdk.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:0.7.0'
    compile 'it.sephiroth.android.library.targettooltip:target-tooltip-library:1.2.9@aar'
    compile 'com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:0.9.+@aar'
    compile 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.isseiaoki:simplecropview:1.0.8'
    compile 'se.emilsjolander:stickylistheaders:2.7.0'
    compile 'com.github.ksoichiro:android-observablescrollview:1.6.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.4.0'
    compile('com.zopim.android:sdk:1.1.1') {
        exclude group: 'com.squareup.picasso'
    }
}
```

And here is volley library added bulild.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.snsepro.mym"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
}
ext {
    supportLibVersion = '23.1.1'  // variable that can be referenced to keep support libs consistent
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://zendesk.artifactoryonline.com/zendesk/repo' }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('libs/gcm.jar')
    compile files('libs/gcm-src.jar')
    compile files('libs/picasso-2.5.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/jsoup-1.7.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/gson-2.2.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/volley.jar')
    compile files('libs/cometchat-sdk.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:0.7.0'
    compile 'it.sephiroth.android.library.targettooltip:target-tooltip-library:1.2.9@aar'
    compile 'com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:0.9.+@aar'
    compile 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.isseiaoki:simplecropview:1.0.8'
    compile 'se.emilsjolander:stickylistheaders:2.7.0'
    compile 'com.github.ksoichiro:android-observablescrollview:1.6.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.4.0'
    compile('com.zopim.android:sdk:1.1.1') {
        exclude group: 'com.squareup.picasso'
    }
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.1'
}
```

Comment: You are compiling every jar in your `libs` folder twice. This line `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])` handles *every* jar in the `libs` folder, you don't need  `compile files('libs/..`)

Comment: Also, you don't need `volley.jar` when you have `compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'`

Comment: yes it is solve i have removed one

Comment: @cricket_007 should get the credits of the answer then, not the one who got the green mark which was written 5 minutes after his comment...

Comment: @GoRoS Thanks but I wasn't sure if that was the solution and I don't need the points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What library is your  **compile files('libs/volley.jar')**  If it is the same one , you will definitely get this error. Try removing either one in that case.