# Unable to build libGdx Android project with freetype - Gradle error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, libgdx, freetype

When trying to build(debug and regular) an Android libGdx project with the freeytpe extention(set up using wiki instructions[https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gdx-freetype]) I get the following error:

> Execution failed for task ':android:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

Same error for regular build.
--stacktrace option gives the following error:

```
> org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':android:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:124)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:80)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:105)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:625)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:580)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
    at com.android.builder.dexing.DxDexArchiveMerger.mergeMonoDex(DxDexArchiveMerger.java:177)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.DxDexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(DxDexArchiveMerger.java:118)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransformCallable.call(DexMergerTransformCallable.java:97)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ExternalLibsMergerTransform.transform(ExternalLibsMergerTransform.kt:121)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:222)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:218)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:213)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:173)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:121)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:122)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:111)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
    at com.android.builder.dexing.DxDexArchiveMerger.lambda$mergeMonoDex$0(DxDexArchiveMerger.java:171)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
    at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:72)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:36)
Caused by: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/freetype/FreeType$Bitmap;
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:661)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:616)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:598)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:198)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:61)
    ... 1 more
```

The actual error seems to be:

> Multiple dex files define Lcom/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/freetype/FreeType$Bitmap

My Gradle files are:
Project:

```
    buildscript {


    repositories {
        google()
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-gradle-plugin:2.3.1'


    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"
    apply plugin: "idea"

    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = "QuickMaze"
        gdxVersion = '1.9.7'
        roboVMVersion = '2.3.1'
        box2DLightsVersion = '1.4'
        ashleyVersion = '1.7.0'
        aiVersion = '1.8.0'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
    }
}

project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "android"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-controllers:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-controllers-android:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"

    }
}

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-controllers:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
        compile fileTree(dir: '../libs', include: '*.jar')
    }
}

project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-controllers-desktop:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-controllers-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-tools:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"

    }
}

project(":ios") {
    apply plugin: "java"
    apply plugin: "robovm"

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-rt:$roboVMVersion"
        compile "com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-cocoatouch:$roboVMVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-robovm:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"

    }
}

tasks.eclipse.doLast {
    delete ".project"
}
```

Android

```
    android {
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    compileSdkVersion 26
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/robovm/ios/robovm.xml'
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.psb.quickmaze"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}


// called every time gradle gets executed, takes the native dependencies of
// the natives configuration, and extracts them to the proper libs/ folders
// so they get packed with the APK.
task copyAndroidNatives() { 
    file("libs/armeabi/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/armeabi-v7a/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/arm64-v8a/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/x86_64/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/x86/").mkdirs();

    configurations.natives.files.each { jar ->
        def outputDir = null
        if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-arm64-v8a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/arm64-v8a")
        if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi-v7a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi-v7a")        
        if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi")
        if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-x86_64.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/x86_64")
        if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-x86.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/x86")
        if(outputDir != null) {
            copy {
                from zipTree(jar)
                into outputDir
                include "*.so"
            }
        }
    }
}

task run(type: Exec) {
    def path
    def localProperties = project.file("../local.properties")
    if (localProperties.exists()) {
        Properties properties = new Properties()
        localProperties.withInputStream { instr ->
            properties.load(instr)
        }
        def sdkDir = properties.getProperty('sdk.dir')
        if (sdkDir) {
            path = sdkDir
        } else {
            path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
        }
    } else {
        path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
    }

    def adb = path + "/platform-tools/adb"
    commandLine "$adb", 'shell', 'am', 'start', '-n', 'com.psb.quickmaze/com.psb.quickmaze.AndroidLauncher'
}

// sets up the Android Eclipse project, using the old Ant based build.
eclipse {
    // need to specify Java source sets explicitly, SpringSource Gradle Eclipse plugin
    // ignores any nodes added in classpath.file.withXml
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs "src", 'gen'
        }
    }

    jdt {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.6
        targetCompatibility = 1.6
    }

    classpath {
        plusConfigurations += [ project.configurations.compile ]        
        containers 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK', 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES'       
    }

    project {
        name = appName + "-android"
        natures 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AndroidNature'
        buildCommands.clear();
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ResourceManagerBuilder"
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.PreCompilerBuilder"
        buildCommand "org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder"
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ApkBuilder"
    }
}

// sets up the Android Idea project, using the old Ant-based build.
idea {
    module {
        sourceDirs += file("src");
        scopes = [ COMPILE: [plus:[project.configurations.compile]]]        

        iml {
            withXml {
                def node = it.asNode()
                def builder = NodeBuilder.newInstance();
                builder.current = node;
                builder.component(name: "FacetManager") {
                    facet(type: "android", name: "Android") {
                        configuration {
                            option(name: "UPDATE_PROPERTY_FILES", value:"true")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I use:
Android Studio 3.0.1
latest versions of Gradle/build-tools

I have tried:
- [Android Studio Gradle error “Multiple dex files define…”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35383351/android-studio-gradle-error-multiple-dex-files-define/35383515)

- [Android Studio Gradle Error: Multiple dex files define](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22851103/android-studio-gradle-error-multiple-dex-files-define)

-And Project->clean

-As Aryan suggested:
enabling multidex

-Excluding dependencies(this seems to be the right path, however it doesn't work):
new gradle file:

```
buildscript {


    repositories {
        google()
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-gradle-plugin:2.3.1'


    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"
    apply plugin: "idea"

    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = "QuickMaze"
        gdxVersion = '1.9.7'
        roboVMVersion = '2.3.1'
        box2DLightsVersion = '1.4'
        ashleyVersion = '1.7.0'
        aiVersion = '1.8.0'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
        google()
    }
}

project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "android"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        compile (project(":core")){
            exclude group: "com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.freetype"
            exclude group: "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform"
        }
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-controllers:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-controllers-android:$gdxVersion"
        /*compile ("com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"){
            exclude group "com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.freetype"
        }*/
        //natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        //natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        //natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        //natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        //natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"

        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    }
}

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-controllers:$gdxVersion"
        //compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
        compile fileTree(dir: '../libs', include: '*.jar')
    }
}

project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-controllers-desktop:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-controllers-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        //compile ("com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-tools:$gdxVersion")


        //compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"

    }
}

project(":ios") {
    apply plugin: "java"
    apply plugin: "robovm"


    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-rt:$roboVMVersion"
        compile "com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-cocoatouch:$roboVMVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-robovm:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
        //compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"

    }
}

tasks.eclipse.doLast {
    delete ".project"
}
```

still depencencies for android are(gradlew android:dependencies):

https://pastebin.com/FQJcr7MV
(moved bcause of character limitations)

-Instant run is disabled.

Note: used Gradle sync after every modification

Possible Problems:
I added the FreeType module and updated Android Studio before doing any builds; the latter may also be a problem(unlikely).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android MultiDex: an all time salvation is imperative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46104198/android-multidex-an-all-time-salvation-is-imperative)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've missing

```
compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
```

Inside your android dependency tag.

What is inside `libs`  folder ? Make sure you're not injecting any library twice in your project.

Comment: I've removed that compile statement for troubleshooting. Same error with and without. The libs folder only contains TweenEngine[link](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Universal-Tween-Engine).

Comment: check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47187662/java-lang-runtimeexception-com-android-builder-dexing-dexarchivemergerexception/47187787#47187787), try to enable multidex

Comment: Didn't work, both clening the project and/or enabling multidex(+Gradle sync) still procude the same error.

Comment: try to disable instant run

Comment: Instant run is disabled.

Comment: add multiDexApplication in AndroidManifest file after you've enabled multidex in build file like this          `<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:allowBackup="false" 
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" >`

Comment: Doesn't work either. Still the same error. But thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

This might shed some light for those still confused:

[Libgdx: More than one file was found with OS independent path 'libgdx-freetype.dylib'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52738361/libgdx-more-than-one-file-was-found-with-os-independent-path-libgdx-freetype-d/52841672#52841672)

```
//implementation "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-tools:$gdxVersion"
```